# Nodejs port with docker is unreachable

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to run node inside a docker container and to expose externally port 8585.
I just want to test the accessibility of the exposed port.

For now, in order to simplify the problem, I excluded Nginx from this setup, I just want to test the nodejs+docker port.

#### The setup:

Nodejs:

```
const PORT = 8585;
const HOST = '127.0.0.1';
app.listen(PORT, HOST);
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:11.10.1
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm install --production --silent
EXPOSE 8585
CMD node index.js
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  mws-client:
    image: mws-client
    build: .
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - '8585'
```

Running the docker image:

```
docker run -p 8585:8585 --expose 8585 1085d876c882
```

Running output:

```
$ docker run -p 8585:8585 --expose 8585 1085d876c882
About 2 run on http://127.0.0.1:8585
Running on http://127.0.0.1:8585
```

Netstat output:

```
$ netstat -a | grep 8585
tcp46      0      0  *.8585                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

Docker ps:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
99d032ce1ad2        1085d876c882        "/bin/sh -c 'node in…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes        0.0.0.0:8585->8585/tcp   inspiring_hypatia
```

Still - no connection:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8585
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:80
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

Please help - clearly I am missing something fundamental (believe me I tested it with so many options..)

Comment: Have you tried setting `ports` in compose file as `8585:8585` and run with `docker-compose up`? (since you are using compose file)

Comment: Hey @ShocKwav3_ , before I do, I have to say that . something is werid regarding the docker-compose.yml file, when I modify it and execute build and push the repository is not updated with a new version, could it be that the docker build doesn't read this file? `Yanivs-MBP:mws-client yanivnuriel$ docker build -t yanivn2000/mws-client .
Yanivs-MBP:mws-client yanivnuriel$ docker push yanivn2000/mws-client`

Comment: probably not but not a strong guess though. Usually when you are running your container it will first be pulled and then run if not present locally.

Comment: Thanks, I will play with the docker configuration files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not with Docker or Host, The issue is in the node application.

you should not bind server to listen `127.0.0.1`.

change your code and bind to `0.0.0.0` and everything will work fine.

```
const PORT = 8585;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';
app.listen(PORT, HOST);
```

you are good to test

```
docker run -p 8585:8585 -it 1085d876c882
```

update compose

```
    ports:
      - "8585:8585"
```

Comment: Thanks! indeed it solved the problem.. `const HOST = '0.0.0.0';`